# Mysql OR Statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a query similar to the following, but am unsure if it will work:

```
UPDATE userbase SET EndDate='today' where Owner='me' OR Owner2='me'
```

I want to update one value where the person using it could be owner one or two, if that makes any sense.

Thank you!

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: If one of our answers helped you, please mark it as correct by clicking the tick. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks correct and should work as intended - assuming you have 2 fields, called `Owner` and `Owner2` and want o check that either of them contains 'me'.

If you want to check if the `Owner` field contains either 'me' or 'me2' you'd do

```
... WHERE Owner = 'me' OR Owner = 'me2'
```

Oh and you may want to consider using the `NOW()` function and similar to set dates/times (In case you're not aware of them).

Comment: Excelent, Thank you, I'm using C# so will just use the DateTime.Now, but thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The statements you wrote looks good, it should be Ok.

For your ref: [SQL UPDATE](http://www.sql-statements.com/sql-update-statement.html)